# C# xml documentation: How to create Notes?

Tags: c#, tags, xml-documentation

I want to achieve a similar thing to the yellow 'Note:' box in the remarks section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms132164%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in my own documentation.

I'm using sandcastle and the sandcastle help file builder to generate a reference website out of the documentation tags. What do I have to write to achieve such a notes box?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
/// <summary><c>Increment</c> method increments the stored number by one. 
/// <note type="caution">
/// note description here
/// </note>
/// </summary>
```

Look at file "C:\Program Files\Sandcastle\Examples\Sandcastle\test.cs"

Type could be one of:

- note
- tip
- caution
- security
- important
- vb/VB/VisualBasic/visual basic note
- cs/CSharp/c#/C#/visual c# note
- cpp/c++/C++/CPP/visual c++ note
- JSharp/j#/J#/visual j# note
- implement
- caller
- inherit

Comment: Cool. That just works! Didn't find the tag in the 'offical' list, but its good to know that also NDoc tags are supported.

Comment: Yes. It is not supported officially, but SandCastle was inspired exactly with NDoc: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sandcastle/archive/2006/11/22/supporting-custom-tags-in-sandcastle.aspx

Comment: THX, +1 from me. Just a side-note: I think you should generally not include <note>s in the <summary> section. <remarks> should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but an alternative:

[NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/content/tags.htm) supports a `<note>` Tag. Since NDoc is outdated, you could have a look for this feature in [NDoc3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/), which is definitely worth looking at since it is also also capable of creating plain HTML documentation, not only online documentation which assumes asp.net.

Comment: Thanks, but our infrastructure already relies on SC and can't be changed that easily.